# Passing class to class attribute

Tags: python, class, attributes

I have a `Cash` class (derived from the `Instrument` class) which has a `.manager` class attribute. This class attribute (an instance of the `Manager` class), when it is initialized, needs to receive the class to which it is attached, as per below.

```py
class Manager: 
    def __init__(self, instrument):
        self.instrument = instrument #instrument is a class (a type)

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.instrument(30.99) #return an instance (e.g. ORM-like operation) 

class Instrument: 
    pass

class Cash(Instrument): 
    manager = Manager(Cash) #this fails... as Cash isn't defined yet

    def __init__(self, amount):
        self.amount = amount
```

**How do we achieve this, i.e. pass one's class to one of its own class attributes at definition?**

Comment: Put the assignment inside the `__init__()` method.  `self.manager = Manager(Cash)`

Comment: You could probably put `self.manager = Manager(type(self))` in `Instrument.__init__`, taking care of this for all future instruments. (Would require `super().__init__` to be called in each subclass, of course.)

Comment: Just do `Cash.manager = Manager(Cash)` after the class definition statement

Comment: @JohnGordon - thanks but can't do that as the manager has to be a class attribute, not an instance attribute (i.e. singleton shared across all instances & needs to be available on class itself).

Answer (score 0):

If you have circular class/attributes, you can use functions that you call after instantiation, in my example `add_A` and `add_B` :

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 1

    def add_B(self, b):
        self.b = b

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 2

    def add_A(self, a):
        self.a = a

a = A()
b = B()
a.add_B(b)
print(a.b.bar)
# 2

b.add_A(a)
print(b.a.foo)
# 1
```